# Comparing Maps by keySet

Tags: java, maps, equals

In the [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html) oracle java it says that:

> Along similar lines, suppose you want to know whether two Map objects
>   contain mappings for all of the same keys.
>
> if (m1.keySet().equals(m2.keySet())) {
>       ... }

I thoroughly understand that it works and also how it works. However would not be easier doing something like :

```
if (m1.equals(m2)){
..}
```

Or for other reasons that I am not seeing it's better using the collection view?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `m1.equals(m2)` is equivalent to `m1.entrySet().equals(m2.entrySet())`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maps can have same **keys** but different **values**:

```
    Map<String, String> m1 = new HashMap<>();
    m1.put("x", "1");
    m1.put("y", "2");

    Map<String, String> m2 = new HashMap<>();
    m2.put("x", "1");
    m2.put("y", "4");

    System.out.println(m1.equals(m2)); // false
    System.out.println(m1.keySet().equals(m2.keySet()));  // true
```

Answer (score 3):

No, because the first way only checks that the key set is equal. That is logically different than determining whether two maps are the same.

Answer (score 3):

The comparison m1.equals(m2) will check that both keys and values are equal between the two maps.

From the Java 7 javadoc:

> boolean equals(Object o)
>
> Compares the specified object with this map for equality. Returns true if the given object is also a map and the two maps represent the same mappings. More formally, two maps m1 and m2 represent the same mappings if m1.entrySet().equals(m2.entrySet()). This ensures that the equals method works properly across different implementations of the Map interface.

Answer (score 1):

Your second example checks something different than your first example.

- In your first example, you only compare the **keys** of two `Map`s, ignoring the values associated with those keys.
- In your second example, you compare both the **keys** and the corresponding **values** of two `Map`s.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are trying to define the equality of a map.  If you want it to be based on keys  you would use the first function:

```
if (m1.keySet().equals(m2.keySet())) { ... }
```

If however you are more interested in the values:

```
if (m1.values().equals(m2.values())) { ... }
```

And if you want to compare the full map:

```
if (m1.entrySet().equals(m2.entrySet())) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

No, the contract in the `Map` interface specifies that `equals()` compares the map's `entrySet()`, which contains the keys *and* values. So, implementations of the `Map` interface (`HashMap` etc.) will abide by that contract.

Comment: `Map` doesn't have an implementation of `equals()`, its an interface.